# Converting all row-column values to column only format

Tags: excel, csv, vbscript

I have an [excel sheet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7eoz0UyQ67LNXdhZTU3Sm1mZmM/view). Please look at "Example Correction" sheet.

I have multiple rows and columns with values. I need all the values in column-only format. That is, **I need all the values from 2465, 2503 and so on till 331806 in single new column**. (Kindly ignore any values after colunm "K" in the sheet).

As there are empty rows intermittently and also unwanted text in the middle areas, I couldn't apply any formula or, VBA script.

Ref: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1172-excel-transpose-multiple-columns-into-one-column.html

I tried VBA script, but it works only when all rows are continuously present.

Here's my code:

```
Sub TableToColumn()
    Dim Rng As Range, LR As Long, i As Long
    LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To LR
        Set Rng = Range("A" & i, "J" & i) 'Change range to suit needs
        Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2).Resize(Rng.Count) =     Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Rng)
    Next i
End Sub
```

This VBA code extract all entries from column A to J, till data exists in rows. How can I apply this into a sheet of entries with more empty rows and unwanted raw text value rows?

Or, via CSV migration and then regex parsing is feasible?

I need the simplest solution for this.

Comment: Why the [Delete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40513540/converting-all-row-column-values-to-column-only-format#40513540) and re-questions without any changes?

Comment: Please show what you have tried.  Stack Overflow is not a code for me service.  As is, this question is too broad and risks down votes and closure.

Comment: The VBA script in the Ref link is what I have tried. I have explained what I did, which doesn't work in my case. What's broad in this question?

Comment: That is a third party tool.  If you cannot make it work I would suggest contacting them and asking.

Comment: That isn't a third party tool. It's VBA code editor built in inside Excel by default.

Comment: Q. Is the range constant i.e. always Range("A7:K1384") ???

Comment: @JReid Nope, that's the issue. There are empty rows and also unwanted (raw text) text rows in the sheet. Please have a look at the [sheet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7eoz0UyQ67LNXdhZTU3Sm1mZmM/view). Sheet name is "Example Correction".

Comment: @ScottCraner the link has a small spiel of VBA that isn't commented for learning purposes. Also, I don't think this user wants transpose. It sounds like they want a collection of values to be listed in one column

Comment: What have you tried to modify the language?  Again Stack overflow is here to help with specific questions, not to rewirte existing code.

Comment: @unix_root, I understand blank rows and non-numeric values, I'm asking does the data always start at row 7 and end at row 1384?

Comment: @ScottCraner I tried modifying the code, but intermittent rows with raw text is the issue.

Comment: Please post the modified attempt and explain what it is doing that is incorrect.

Comment: @JReid Yes. I need only this sheet to be converted. Not from A7, but from from B7 till K1384. But, again, the row header(DIP header) appears in every page of the sheet. I need to extract only the values from 2465 to 331806 (excluding DIP headers).

Comment: @ScottCraner I have already said that code is only applicable with data in continuous order. I'm asking the optimistic and fastest way to extract the specified data.

Comment: That question is too broad for this forum.  The answer is: Yes, there are many ways to do this.

Comment: Now it is asking for an opinion which is also not applicable for this forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay then let's try this ...

```
Public Sub Answer()

Dim RowCnt as Integer 
Dim Output as Variant 
Dim Data as Variant
Data = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("EXAMPLE CORRECTION").Range("B7:K1384")

' How many rows will we have ?
RowCnt=0
for Row = LBound(Data, 1) to UBound(Data, 1)
    for Col = LBound(Data, 2) to UBound(Data, 2)
        if Not IsEmpty(Data(Row, Col)) and IsNumeric(Data(Row, Col)) Then RowCnt=RowCnt+1;
    Next Col
Next Row    
' Resize Output
Redim Output(1 to RowCnt, 1) as Variant
' Fill Output
RowCnt=1
for Row = LBound(Data, 1) to UBound(Data, 1)
    for Col = LBound(Data, 2) to UBound(Data, 2)
        if Not IsEmpty(Data(Row, Col)) and IsNumeric(Data(Row, Col)) Then
            Output(RowCnt, 1) = Data(Row, Col)
            RowCnt=RowCnt+1
        end if
    next
next
' Write to Some Column (Column L) for now
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("EXAMPLE CORRECTION").Range("L7:L" & RowCnt+6) = Output

End Sub
```

Comment: This should be a good start for you, you should be able to debug and correct any issues you face.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have added `And Data(Row, Col) > 1` to remove rows with DIY headers (0.1, 0.2, and so on). And, pasting total Output to a range doesn't work. I have edited it to paste values by every cell. Works like charm.